Media3 ExoPlayer PlayerView UI - seekbar doesn't work (change position) and rewind/fast forward buttons are disabled on local MKV file
I'm trying to play a local MKV formatted video file in Media3 using MediaBuilder with ExoPlayer Builder. There is no issue with playing the video, but when I pause the video, it does start again.
MediaItem.Builder()
    .setUri(uri)
    .setMimeType(APPLICATION_MATROSKA)
    .setSubtitleConfigurations(playerParams.subtitles.toSubtitleMediaItem())
    .build()

ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .setSeekBackIncrementMs(SEEK_INTERVAL)
            .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(SEEK_INTERVAL)
            .setTrackSelector(trackSelectorDataSource.trackSelector)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(
                DefaultMediaSourceFactory(
                    context, DefaultExtractorsFactory().apply {
                        setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled(true)
                    }
                )
            )
            .build().also {
                _player = it
            }


Check logs share it by editing the question
